# Yii 2, active record, with

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii2

how can i get a set of data, based on condition in relation table?

In Yii 1 i could use `with()` and `'on'` statement. This doesn't work in Yii 2, or i can't find any good example.
For example in Yii 1 i could write this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('works'=>array('on' => 'works.user_id=t.id AND (works.work_id=$SOMEVALUE OR ...)'));
```

I tried something like this (`userRight` is my relation):

```
Foo::find()->with(['userRight'=>['on'=>['user_r'=>$this->id]]]);
```

Is there any solution in Yii 2?

Answer (score 1):

From official example:

```
$orders = Order::find()->innerJoinWith([
    'customer' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('customer.created_at > ' . (time() - 24 * 3600))
              ->onCondition(['category_id' => 1]);
    }
])->all();
```

See [this link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md)

Answer (score 0):

if in your table have a relation and using gii to generate models, controller and view it will make function for the relation.
if no you can make function to declare relation 2 tables in model

```
public function getWorks()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Works::className(), ['id' => 'works_id']);
}
```

if hasMany just flip id.

and call the function

```
Foo::find()->joinWith('works')->all();
```